Does Henry Rice's doctoral dissertation exist online?
Henry Gordon Rice is perhaps best known for Rice's theorem, which states that any non-trivial semantic property of Turing machines is undecidable. In a footnote to his Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. article (74 (2), 358-366, 1953), Rice indicates that

Most of the results in this paper were contained in a thesis written under Professor Paul Rosenbloom [...] and presented toward the degree of Doctor of Philosophy at Syracuse University.

Is this thesis available anywhere online, or has anyone contacted Syracuse to obtain a digital copy of Rice's work?

Go chat with your local friendly research librarian and let them at it.
